# How to insert array into another array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

How to push array in another array using JavaScript?

Example:-

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
var b = [6,7,8,9,10]
i want to push a & b into c
var c =[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want `c` to equal `[[1,2,3,4,5],[,6,7,8,9,10]]` or `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`?

Comment: i want c like this [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

Comment: @Phoenix use `.push()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what sam said is enough:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [6,7,8,9,10];
var c =[];
c.push(a);
c.push(b);
```

To convert to JSON:

> var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);

And to get it into an object :

> var arrFromJson = JSON.parse( myJsonString );

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you just have to create another array to do it:

```
var c = [a,b];
```

Then, you can use `.push` to add more arrays.

```
c.push([11,12,13]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [6,7,8,9,10];
var c =[];
c.push(a);
c.push(b);
```

Comment: and how to push c into JSON

Comment: What do you mean by "push into JSON"? if you want to add it to an object you can do `yourObject['keyOfYourChoice']=c;` and access it with `yourObject['keyOfYourChoice']` or `yourObject.keyOfYourChoice`

Comment: If by "push to JSON" you mean "convert to a JSON String" you can use `JSON.stringify(c)` in [supporting browsers](http://caniuse.com/json)

Comment: @sam sorry for that confusing statement, I want to add it to an object Thanks sam